# How can I do redraw the shape of my UIView and give it a shadow in the same time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

My UIView+Shape.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface UIView (Shape)

- (void)setShape:(CGPathRef)shape;

@end
```

My UIView+Shape.m file

```
#import "UIView+Shape.h"

@implementation UIView (Shape)

- (void)setShape:(CGPathRef)shape
{
    if (shape == nil) {
        self.layer.mask = nil;
    }

    CAShapeLayer* maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.path = shape;
//    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.80;
}

@end
```

My UIBezierPath+BasicShape.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIBezierPath (BasicShape)

+ (UIBezierPath *)cutCorner:(CGRect)originalFrame length:(CGFloat)length;

@end
```

My UIBezierPath+BasicShape.m file

```
#import "UIBezierPath+BasicShape.h"

@implementation UIBezierPath (BasicShape)

+ (UIBezierPath *)cutCorner:(CGRect)originalFrame length:(CGFloat)length
    {
    CGRect rect = originalFrame;
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    [bezierPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width - length, 0)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width - length, 15)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width, 25)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width - length, 35)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width - length, rect.size.height)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, rect.size.height)];
    [bezierPath closePath];
    return bezierPath;
}

@end
```

By importing these two classes and using a sentence like

```
[filterList setShape:[UIBezierPath cutCorner:filterList.bounds length:10].CGPath];
```

filterlist is my UIView.

The result is [image: annotate 'self.layer.mask = maskLayer;']

and [image: annotate another two sentences]

But I just wanna get both of these effects for this view.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What a foolish question! 
I just create an another shadowView at the back of my filterListView and then get the effect what I want!

Comment: You shouldn't add unnecessary views on screen,

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative, add a sublayer with shadow already set.

```
CAShapeLayer* maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = shape;
maskLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
maskLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.80;
maskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
[self.layer addSublayer:maskLayer];
```